# java NIO socket: network activity continues after I exit program

Tags: sockets, tcp

This doesn't seem to make sense but:

I am on a slow 10 MBPS link. If I initiate sending a large 13 MB file using
NIO sockets, and then exit my program, I see that network activity continues for some
time.

I would have thought that exiting the process would terminate any sending.

Any ideas?

Comment: See how much of the data your program has passed to operating system level buffers before exit.  Perhaps (have to check the docs) that will still try to transmit over the wire.

Comment: what do you mean by exit your program? The JDK tools? or?

Comment: Did you try closing the Socket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is pending data to be sent when the socket is closed, it will continue to be sent after the socket is closed until either it is all sent or an error occurs. Both writing and closing are asynchronous in TCP.

This is not peculiar to NIO or even Java.

Comment: Thanks, EJP. Does it make sense that there are MBs of pending data to be sent? Because I see network activity for 10s of seconds after closing the socket. Also, is there a way of aborting the send?

Comment: It only makes sense if your socket send buffer is megabytes big. That's where the pending data is. You can abort the send by a certain setting of SO_LINGER which you will find in the Javadoc for Socket.setSoLinger(), which I will not repeat here as it is a facility more abused than used.

Comment: Thanks. So, unusual, but not impossible.